# Double nested classes

Tags: java, class, constructor, nested

I've been trying to make a person and after version three, decided to start over from scratch, after I learned about the existence of nested classes. So far, I've typed this in:

```
public class Person {
    public Person() {
        side left = new side();
        side.limb arm = left.new limb();
        left.arm.hi();
        // Arm can not be resolved or is not a field.
    }

    class side {
        class limb {
            public void hi() {
                System.out.println("Hi");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

How do I fix this? I've never tried nesting classes within classes and I really want this to work, but:

1. It needs to be written in only one class file, so I can have nested classes but only one big public class file.
2. I want to be able to use the left arm's methods using "arm.left.method" or "left.arm.method." because I want to specify which arm I'm talking about.

Comment: Check here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html

Comment: `left` is instance of `side` class and this class doesn't have any `arm` field so you can't use `left.arm`. What you are trying to achieve here? Is it perhaps `arm.hi()` instead of `left.arm.hi()` (here `arm` is **local** variable created in constructor, not **field** of `side` class)?

Comment: Not sure if your syntax is okay. But if anything it's not `left.arm.hi();`, it's just `arm.hi();`. arm is a pointer on it's own, not part of left, in your code.

Comment: Just rename your `arm` pointer to `leftArm`

Comment: Your "only one class file" requirement means you can't use this approach.  Nested classes compile into separate class files.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is that you are treating Limb as if it were a member-variable within the Side class. i.e. you are using side.limb as if the class were written:

```
class Side {
    public Limb sidesLimb;

    class Limb {
        public void hi();
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
Side left = new Side();
left.sidesLimb = new Limb();
left.sidesLimb.hi();
```

Bsically, you forgot to add a member-variable of type Limb within the Side class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. What I did in order to retain my ability to specify which side it is, is the following:

```
public class Person{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Person joe = new Person();  
}
public Person(){
doubleLimb arm = new doubleLimb();
arm.left.hi();
}
class doubleLimb{
    limb right;
    limb left;
    public doubleLimb(){
        left = new limb();
        right = new limb();
    }
}
class limb{
    public void hi(){
    System.out.println("Hi");
    }
    }
}
```

What it does is basically for things that have a left and a right, it makes the limb name be the name of an empty class that just creates new limbs named left and right.